# Ubuntu 13.10 gives "Package 'libapache2-mod-auth-mysql' has no installation candidate" error

Tags: package-management, apache2, php

**UPDATE:**
Because Apache 2.4 is the default version (instead of the previous 2.2) this error occurs.  However as can be seen [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mod-auth-mysql/+bug/1243076/comments/18) all future versions of Ubuntu 13.10 and above will not support this package until it gets fixed upstream.  As a work around you do *not* need to install this package as it is only required for Apache authentication against MySQL (as opposed to doing it at the web app end, which is far more common)

I'm trying to install my LAMP environment on Ubuntu 13.10 using my script file that can be found [here](https://github.com/JohnRCrawford/devEnvironment/blob/master/stage1.sh).  That script worked for Ubuntu 12.04, Ubuntu 13.04 but when I try it on Ubuntu 13.10 it gives the following error:

```
   E: Package 'libapache2-mod-auth-mysql' has no installation candidate
```

Any idea on how to fix this?  Note, I do want this package to be installed.

EDIT: I've found out now that the reason this could not be installed was because it needed the following two packages that were missing: libmysqlclient16 and apache2.2-common.  Do I just need to install these packages or were they removed for a reason?

Comment: **Bug Confirmed** https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/software-center/+bug/1243076

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like there's a bug logged for this.

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/software-center/+bug/1243076

Comment: Thanks for the update.  Just a quick question, when/if they fix this bug (I'm hoping they do fix it as setting up a LAMP environment is pretty damn important imho), how do I get this "updated" code?  Do I just need to run a "sudo apt-get update"?

Comment: @JohnCrawford: Provided they uploaded their patch into official repositories, then yes.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to install it manually by downloading deb package from:
https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/saucy/amd64/libapache2-mod-auth-mysql/4.3.9-13.1ubuntu1

But libapache2-mod-auth-mysql depends on apache2.2-common:
https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/saucy/amd64/apache2.2-common/2.2.22-6ubuntu5

And apache2.2-common depends on apache2.2-bin:
https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/saucy/amd64/apache2.2-bin/2.4.6-2ubuntu2

Apache2.2-bin has no dependencies, but to install it you have to remove gnome-user-share.
Gnome user share is needed to share over bluetooth and WebDAV.
Probably this incompatibility is the reason why installing libapache2-mod-auth-mysql has been disabled.

After removing gnome-user-share I've managed to install apache2.2-bin, but apache2.2-common breaks in conflict with apache2-bin which is needed by apache2.2-bin. It is blocked this way and I didn't find any solution to that problem.